# Executing jquery function from a with class problems

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hover, conflict

I've set up the navigation on my site with links within the children of a list.  The links have text that is tabbed off so that only the image shows.  For 2 of the links I want to show specific sub navigation via jquery hover.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work as easily as planned.  You can see here http://serratedfoundation.com/test/

At the top left of the page is a link without the tabbed off text that shows the functionality I'm looking to attain when hovering over the "services" image.  I understand this is fairly elementary and is probably caused by the way I've set up the CSS of the nav.  That said, I'm not experienced enough to pinpoint the problem even though I've troubleshot it with the aforementioned link.  Additionally, if anyone could provide a link for how to use firebug to troubleshoot Javascript, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function inside `jQuery(document).ready()`

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready( function(){

    j(".navServices").hover(function () {
        j("#subNavWrap").show();
    }, function() { //on hover out...
        j("#subNavWrap").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you kindly for the prompt help!